Exoplayer hangs subtitles on the last dialogue
It's been a long since I last posted.
I've got a problem which I cannot solve since I upgraded from exoplayer 2.8.4 to 2.11.1. I know I have a very old version of it but upgrading to 2.18.+ is giving me tons of errors.
Subtitles can be hidden manually, switched between languages, etc, using the DefaultTrackSelector. But after I upgraded, the last dialogue keeps showing and won't dissappear until new text comes. If there is no dialogue, the same text can be shown for minutes without dissappearing.
It has been working fine for older versions for years but now its broken.
Working with embeded subtitles.
Any advice?
Tried upgrading to any newer version but I get tons of errors which I cannot handle

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This was a bug in exoplayer 2.11.1 with certain video formats. It was solved when upgrading exoplayer to 2.13.3 or higher.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
